# How to remove escape characters in JsonOutput.toJson

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to escape the double quotes in my json file.

But whenever it goes to `JsonOutput.toJson` the `\` reappear.

Here's my code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def script = new File('${file}')

def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(script.text)

def text = JsonOutput.toJson(content)
```

Here's my file:

```
{
  "admin_id": "admin_user",
  "admin_pwd": "admin_password",
  "commands": [
"command one",
"command two",
"command \"three\" with double quotes",
"command four"
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"admin_id": "admin_user","admin_pwd": "admin_password","commands":["command one","command two","command "three" with double quotes","command four"]}
```

The escape character `\` should not be in the output.

Comment: So you _want_ invalid json?

Comment: @tim_yates will it be an invalid json if the escape character ```\``` is removed in the .json file? Sorry, I am pretty new at groovy and json.

Comment: @tim_yates I tried to validate it at https://jsonlint.com/. Yes, it is invalid json file.  Thank you, I got an idea.